# Detect an application even if its name has been changed with WM_SETTEXT?

Tags: delphi

I am developing a program in Delphi. I want this program to detect if another program X is running and close it. I've seen that you can change the name of any program with the `WM_SETTEXT` message and give it another
name.

Is there any way to see the real name of the program even though its name has been changed with WM_SETTEXT?

Comment: You need to find some way to identify this program

Comment: that way you can advise me to identify the program don't imporat that language so I see? Thank you for your response

Comment: It all depends. There's no one answer. Find something unique about it.

Comment: Applications often have unique [window classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632596.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable: Of course, unless the app is written in VCL by a beginner who doesn't know how to change the default class names of the app's Form windows.  Having multiple such apps running at the same time (which is not uncommon) would make it hard to differentiate them by class names alone.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: *"Applications **often** have unique window classes‌​."*

Comment: Appart from *how* to do it: *why* do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the `.exe` filename of the desired program, you can use `EnumWindows()` to enumerate the available running windows.  In its callback function for each `HWND` detected, use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` and `OpenProcess()` to open a `HANDLE` to the process that owns the window, and then use `GetModuleFileName/Ex()`, `GetProcessImageFileName()`, or `QueryFullProcessImageName()` to retrieve its filename.  Once you find the filename you are interested in, you will know which `HWND`(s) belong to that process, and can then close it/them as needed.

Comment: Of course, exe file can be renamed very easily.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: True, but it is something to consider nonethess, if no other unique identifier can be gleemed from the window itself.